# How to change the output filename of a raster using sentinel-hub?

Tags: raster, tiff, geotiff, sentinelsat

I'm downloading satellite images using sentinel hub. 
Everything is going fine, but I would like to change the downloaded raster name by the date of the image, for example.

```
wcs_request_vi_filter_ernesto = WcsRequest(layer='NDVI',
                     bbox= pivo_bbox,
                     time=time_interval,
                     resx='20m', resy='20m',
                     instance_id=INSTANCE_ID,
                     maxcc= 0.1,
                     image_format=MimeType.TIFF_d32f,
                     custom_url_params={CustomUrlParam.SHOWLOGO: False})
wcs_request_vi_filter_ernesto.data_folder = r'C:\Users\Ana\Areas_Ernesto'
wcs_request_vi_filter_ernesto.save_data()
```

Does anyone know how to change this?

Thanks very much